# Nginx + Node deploy

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment

I'm setting up node,js and nginx on the server. I haven't done this for a long time and now I'm facing a problem. That after the command
`cerbot --nginx` 
it displays only the server (his name server.hosting.com) itself by default in the list of possible domains  [image]

etc/nginx/sites-avalible/default :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I changed this to and restarted nginx but the result is the same:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name myurl.com; 

    root /home/project;  

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $Host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

How can I tell him the correct folder and domain? Now even if you go to the server’s IP address there is nothing? And certbot also does not see the second domain myurl.com. On the hosting of the domain, I set all the records as the IP address of the server. in home/project there is my ready-made image from gitlab